# TeamCity -- is it possible to associate a timeout value with a specific build step?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have a build configuration consisting of several steps, and I would like to see one specific step fail if it runs longer than a certain time threshold (say, 10 seconds). I don't want to introduce timeout to the entire build (i.e.  all steps) which could take several minutes, among other reasons because the time overrun of this specific step should fail the entire build, therefore there is no need to run any subsequent steps.

I know I can implement the timeout feature in a shell or Perl wrapper script reasonably easily; my question is about the TeamCity's support for this feature.

Is there a way to do this via TeamCity build configuration?

I am using TeamCity v7.1

Answer (score 2):

Currently, TeamCity does not support this feature. There is a similar request in [our tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21460). Although it requests this issue for .Net build runners, it can be expanded to handle other build runner types. You can watch/vote for issue to be notified when it's implemented